# Two real valued functions on a complete measure, X=Y a.s., then X is measurable iff Y is measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Given $(\Omega, \mathscr{A},P)$, let $\mathscr{A}^{\prime}=\{A\cup N\colon A\in\mathscr{A},N\in\mathscr{N}\}$, where $\mathscr{N}$ are the null sets. Suppose $X=Y$ a.s. where $X$ and $Y$ are two real-valued functions on $\Omega$. Show that $X\colon (\Omega,\mathscr{A}^{\prime})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$ is measurable if and only if $Y\colon(\Omega,\mathscr{A}^{\prime})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$ is measurable.

We only need to show one way since we can exchange $X$ and $Y$ in the proof after proving $(\Rightarrow )\colon$

$X$ measurable $\implies$ $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{A}^{\prime}$  $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}$

How can I use the fact that $X=Y$ almost surely to rewrite $X^{-1}(b)$ as a union of something belonging to $\mathscr{B}$ and the null set?

$$X^{-1}(A)=\left( X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(A)^c \right) \cup\left( X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(A)\right)$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [measurability of a random variable coming from a.s. equivalence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241365/measurability-of-a-random-variable-coming-from-a-s-equivalence)

Comment: @StefanHansen I am not convinced that this is a duplicate. This is a "help me with this specific step" question, not a "tell me the whole answer!" question.

Comment: @user1729: Writing $X^{-1}(A)$ "as a union of something belonging to $\mathscr B$ and the null set" is the whole answer.

Comment: @StefanHansen Okay, you convinced me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since the space is complete, if $N$ is a null set, then $f \cdot 1_N$ is measurable for **any** function $f$ (measurable or not).

Let $N$ be the set on which $X,Y$ differ. This is a null set by assumption.

Since you can write $Y = Y 1_N + X 1_{N^c}$, it is immediate that $Y$ is measurable if $X$ is.